# Something like WHERE clause with csv-file

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv-file (semi-colon-seperated) and get it into php like this;

```
$file_handle = fopen("data.csv", "r");
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
  $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 0, ";");
  print $line_of_text[0] . $line_of_text[1] ((...etc));
  }
fclose($file_handle);
```

I would like to **print/echo all rows containing a certain keyword**. I am hoping I could pop in something like:

```
"SELECT file_handle WHERE line_of_text[3] LIKE '%keyword'"
```

but, as far as I can tell, the WHERE clause is mySQL only?

So any nice tips on this are most welcome :-)

edit:
My csv looks something like this:
ID; Date; First name; Last name; Value (integer); Value (integer)
94; 15-11-14; John; Smith; 329,00; 500
95; 15-11-15; James; Jones; 211,00; 600

Comment: The function you're looking for is [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

Comment: @wogsland - "Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string" but I need all occurences?

Comment: Perhaps I should add; I need to **echo all the rows containing keyword (-s)**

Comment: @RyanVincent - never even heard of SQLite! I have some reading up to do it seems. I do fear, however, that I will run into another mess - but I will certainly give it a shot.

Comment: Well it seems my host is only on **limited SQLite support**. I have to use PDO-module... can of worms! 2 new frontiers at once, all because I cannot make a csv-wildcard work (although many more problems may occur on the other side of this particular pickle)

Answer (score 0):

try filtering the array $line_of_text with `in_array`  function

```
<?php
$row = 1;
$your_value_to_search = 'your_value';
if (($handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
   while (($line_of_text = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
     if (in_array( $your_value_to_search, $line_of_text)) {
         $num = count($line_of_text);
         for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $line_of_text[$c] . "<br />\n";
         }
      }

      $row++;

  }
  fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks so far (not working for me yet). Is the for $c the specific "column" in my csv-set where my keyword(-s) are located? And why the 1000-value in fopen?

Comment: 1000 for open is for specify the max row lenght is just for sample. And i have update the answer . a piece was missing...

Comment: Better :-) Now I can search and print exact hits from the first cell (see csv example above) so I can get 94 and the rest of that row. And if I have that row twice I'll get it printed twice. But I cannot get hits from the other cells. Search for 'John'  gets no hits? And is there som sort of **wildcard** I can use so a search for '9%' would yield both 94 and 95?

Comment: Sorry. I missed out on "spaces" so I had a lot of "...; John; Smith;...". Searching for ' John' WITH the space made all of the difference. **Still no luck with the wildcard though!** ' Jo'+'%' just puts out everything, ' Jo%' or ' Jo' . '%' puts out nothing.

Comment: If my answer is useful please rate it and/or mark as accepte. in_array macth exact pattern no wildchart. For wildchart you can use preg_rep using regular expression and callback function...

Comment: So what you are saying is that your solution will not going to work with a wildcard search? That is more or less critical for my project.

Comment: For widlcard you must use reg_exp and php related function. there are some function for search with wildcard in array...